# Validity of Jordan's lemma

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the following integral

$$ \int_0^\infty dx \, e^{ix}$$

with contour integration. By choosing a quarter circle contour $\gamma$, by the residue theorem we get

\begin{align} 
0 =\oint_\gamma dz \, e^{iz} =& \int_0^\infty dx\, e^{ix} + \int_{\mathrm{Arc}} dz \, e^{iz} -i\int_0^\infty dy \, e^{-y} \\
=& \int_0^\infty dx\, e^{ix} + \int_{\mathrm{Arc}} dz \, e^{iz} -i
\end{align}

therefore, if the integral over the arc is zero, the original integral becomes $i$.

Can Jordan's lemma, of a variation thereof, be applied in this case?

Edit: the parametrization would be $z=R e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Aside: it seems to me that the original integral can be interpreted as a distribution as the Fourier transform of the theta function at $k=1$, which would give $i$ as well.

Comment: If this is actually meant as a standard integral, then it is not convergent, since the integrand has constant norm 1.

Comment: What do you mean by standard integral? $e^{ix^2}$ also has norm 1, but it converges.

Comment: I mean the Riemann or Lesbegue intergral. The integral of $e^{ix^2}$ from 0 to infinity also doesn't converge, since you can find arbitrarily large numbers $N$ such that 

$\int_0^N e^{ix^2}dx = 0$ or $\left|\int_0^N e^{ix^2}dx\right| = \left|\int_0^{\pi}e^{ix}\right|>0$

Comment: Also, you could just argue by the tail lemma for definate integrals (the sequence $\int_N^{\infty}f(x)dx$ goes to 0 for $N$ going to infinity if the integral is convergent).

Comment: @RichardJensen Such a sequence does not exist, since both the real and imaginary parts are strictly positive, as they are the Fresnel integrals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral. There are many answers which provide a computation of the integral of $e^{ix^2}$ already https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952056/computing-the-integral-int-expix2-dx, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522926/integral-of-eix2

Comment: 1. No, $e^{i\sqrt{\pi}^2}= - 1$, so has negative real part.

2. The wikipedia article's calculation for the infinity limit is nonsense, since it evaluates cosine at infinity, which is undefined.

3. I haven't read the entire argument from the SE post, but the top comment to the answer states the same that I do. 

4. Check @Nico Terry's answer, there you can see exactly what goes wrong.

5. I'm guessing this is a problem from physics or enginering? The reason I'm thinking this is that in those disciplines, people are loose with math, and use "wrong" resulats if they just work.

Comment: @RichardJensen what I mean was that $F(x)=\int_0^x dt \, e^{it^2}$ has positive real and imaginary parts for all $x$. Are you impliying that the plots $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ on wikipedia are wrong? The integral of $e^{ix}$ is indeed undefined though, because as you say cosine and sine have no asymptotic limit

Comment: Okay, I see. Well, it has non-negativ real and imaginary part, since it evaluates to 0 at for example 0 and $\sqrt{2\pi}$. And it turns out that I read the article on wikipedia wrong. Those Fresner integrals are indeed convergent (there is a misprint on the wikipedia article which confused me where they use $e^{t^2}$ instead of the correct $e^{-t^2}$, but I digress), so apologies for that, you were indeed right. I remembered the theorem wrong, the integrand does not have to go to zero for the integral to be convergent!

Comment: @RichardJensen by the way I was indeed asking from a physics background! I guess physicists don't care about convergence as always

Comment: It is divergent but concerning distribution theory see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903341) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851922).

Answer (score 2):

That integral is not well-defined because for any horizontal line $z=x+iy,e^{iz}$ follows the circle of radius $e^{-y}$ in the complex plane. Therefore, symmetry shows us that the integral $\int_0^{2n\pi}e^{ix}dx=0$ but $\int_0^{(2n+1)\pi} e^{ix}dx=\left. \frac{1}{i}e^{ix}\right|_0^\pi=-i(-1-1)=2i$. Jordan's lemma will not allow you to solve the improper integral, because no solution exists. The reason for this is that the proof of Jordan's lemma relies on the symmetry $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$, so only the half-circular arc in the upper half-plane can apply it. However, if you want to apply a similar result, you could instead consider the maximum modulus of the function over that interval (in this case, that approach fails because $|e^{ix}|=1$ for all real $x$).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is that, as pointed out by Nico Terry, the integral does not converge. However, it can be assigned a value by analytic continuation as follows

$$ f(z)=\int_0^\infty dt \, e^{zt} = -\frac{1}{z}, \qquad \mathrm{for\, Re}(z) < 0 $$

so we can analytically continue $f(z)$ over all $\mathbb C -\{0\}$. Hence $f(i)=i$ means that we can assign the value $i$ to the original integral.