# computing contour integeral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\alpha x^2} x^{2a} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number and $a$ a positive integer.
I want to compute the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\alpha x^2} x^{2a} dx$.

By choosing a principal branch I have a well defined $z = \alpha^{1/2}$, and by changing the variable I get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\alpha x^2} x^{2a} dx =  z^{-1 - 2a} \int_{ z \mathbb{R}} e^{- x^2} x^{2a} dx. 
$$
I am struggling to  show
$$
z^{-1 - 2a} \int_{ z \mathbb{R}} e^{- x^2} x^{2a} dx = z^{-1 - 2a} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{- x^2} x^{2a} dx
$$
which is supposed to follow from a contour integration argument. any clarification appreciated!

Comment: (A little remark; not an answer to your question) The result to be found is classical:  See [here](https://srabbani.com/moments.pdf)

Comment: @TravisWillse That is not what he is asking about. He is asking how to prove that the change of integration from $z\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is valid. This is not overly difficult, but it is indeed tedious.

Comment: @JeanMarie The integral is running along the $z^{2a}\ $ branch-cut !!!. So, it should choose another branch instead of the $\underline{principal}$ one.

Comment: @FelixMarin The link given by JeanMarie is regarding a real integral so there are no issues with branch cut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'd like to calculate the integral
$$\int_{0}^\infty t^{n}\exp(-z^2t^2)\mathrm dt\tag{1}$$
Note that it converges only when $\operatorname{Re}(z^2)>0$.

And what we've done is introduce the new variable $s=zt$ which changes it to
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{n}\exp(-z^2t^2)\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{z\infty}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds$$

And we'd like to prove that we can rotate the path of integration without any issues, i.e
$$\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\int_0^{z\infty}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds=\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\int_0^{\infty}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds\tag{2}$$

---

I carry out an almost identical calculation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522926/integral-of-eix2/4534264#4534264) though this case is actually easier because there is no singularity at the origin. We consider a sector in the complex plane:

[image: diagram]

We denote this sector by $C(r)$. Explicitly,
$$C_1(r)=\{t\mid t\in[0,r]\} \\ C_2(z,r)=\{r\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}\mid t\in[0,\operatorname{arg}z]\} \\ C_3(z,r)=\{zt\mid t\in[r,0]\} \\ C(z,r)=C_1(r)\cup C_2(z,r)\cup C_3(z,r)$$

Obviously my diagram assumes $\operatorname{Re}z,\operatorname{Im}z>0$ but this calculation is easily repeatable in any of the four quadrants. We know, because we are dealing with an integrand that is analytic everywhere on and in the contour, that
$$0=\oint_{C(z,r)}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds=\left(\int_{C_1(r)}+\int_{C_2(z,r)}+\int_{C_3(z,r)}\right)s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds$$

Now, obviously what we'd like to show is that $\int_{C_3(z,r)}s^n\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds\to 0$ as $r\to\infty$. This is actually quite tedious. First see that
$$\int_{C_3(z,r)}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds=\int_{0}^{\operatorname{arg}z}r^n\mathrm e^{\mathrm int}\exp(-r^2\mathrm e^{2\mathrm it})~\mathrm ir\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}\mathrm dt$$

By the estimation lemma,
$$\left|\int_{0}^{\operatorname{arg}z}r^n\mathrm e^{\mathrm int}\exp(-r^2\mathrm e^{2it})~\mathrm ir\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}\mathrm dt\right|\leq \int_{0}^{\operatorname{arg}z}\left|r^{n+1}\exp(-r^2\mathrm e^{2\mathrm it})\right|\mathrm dt$$

Then,
$$\left|r^{n+1}\exp(-r^2\mathrm e^{2\mathrm it})\right|=r^{n+1}\bigg|\exp\big(-r^2(\cos(2t)+\mathrm i\sin(2t))\big)\bigg| \\ =r^{n+1}\bigg|\exp(-r^2\cos(2t))\bigg|$$

Which allows us to deduce (via a simple change of variable $2t\to t$)
$$\left|\int_{C_3(z,r)}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}r^{n+1}\int_{0}^{2\operatorname{arg}z}\exp(-r^2\cos t)\mathrm dt$$

At this point, things become a little tricky. Note that
$$\operatorname{Re}(z^2)>0\implies\begin{matrix}|\operatorname{arg}z|<\pi /4 \\ \text{or}\\|\operatorname{arg}(-\overline{z})|<\pi/4\end{matrix}$$

I will focus on the right half plane, i.e $|\operatorname{arg}z|<\pi /4$. (Again, this calculation is easily repeatable for the other side of the plane.) From this we know that $2\operatorname{arg}z\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. This allows us to deduce that $\exp(-r\cos(t))$ is *increasing* for $t\in[0,2\operatorname{arg} z]$. Letting $2\operatorname{arg} z=\phi$ for short this allows us to bound
$$\left|\int_{C_3(z,r)}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds\right|\leq \frac{1}{2}r^{n+1}\int_{0}^{\phi}\exp(-r^2\cos t)\mathrm dt\leq \frac{r^{n+1}}{2}\int_{0}^{\phi}\exp(- r^2\cos \phi)\mathrm dt$$

So
$$\left|\int_{C_3(z,r)}s^{n}\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds\right|\leq \frac{\phi}{2}r^{n+1}\exp(- r^2\cos \phi)$$
Which clearly goes to $0$ as $r\to\infty$, as $\cos \phi>0$. It is not so easy in my [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522926/integral-of-eix2/4534264#4534264) because in that case we had $\phi=\pi/2$.

Now, for the finishing touches. We can see that
$$\int_{0}^{z\infty} s^n\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds=\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{C_2(z,r)}s^n\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds$$
And, our above argument shows that $\int_{C_2}\to\int_{C_1}$ as $r\to \infty$ hence
$$\int_0^{z\infty}s^n\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds=\int_0^{\infty}s^n\exp(-s^2)\mathrm ds$$

This integral is easy to calculate using the Gamma function. It is also easy to see that this can be extended to complex values of $n$ which allows us to finally write (substituting $z^2\to z$ and $n\to \nu-1$)

$$\boxed{\int_0^\infty t^{\nu-1}\exp(-zt^2)=\frac{1}{2z^{\nu/2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right) \\ \text{for}~\big(\operatorname{Re}(z)>0~\text{and}~\operatorname{Re}(\nu)>0\big)}$$

Comment: Sorry about my inconsistent use of $z^2$ or $z$. I thought that for the proof using the contour integration $z^2$ was better, but the final formula I think looks better with just $z$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!